# Scale conversion of $\mu$ second to seconds and seconds to seconds

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

I want to generate random numbers that follow Poisson distribution but I have to express $\lambda$ in microseconds and software tool accepts only seconds. So I when  I write $1*10^{-6}$, software does not generate number as expected.

I want to shift the scale: I want to represent $1$ $ \mu s$ with $1$ second. Is it correct that $1$ second will then be represented by $1*10^6$ seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dangerous to use seconds in both the original and target time scales.

Certainly, if you want to let $1\ \mu s$ denote one time unit, then $1\ s$ will be given by $1\times 10^6$ time units.